# Filtering a XsltListViewWebPart that has "Send Row of Data To“ connection doesn’t work?

Tags: filter, xslt-list-view-web-part

Filtering of a XsltListViewWebPart is absolutely no problem when you change the 
webPart.XmlDefinition property like this:

```
                    var xml = new XmlDocument();
             xml.LoadXml(webPart.XmlDefinition); 
            var viewXml = xml["View"]; 
            if (viewXml != null)
             {
                 var viewQuery = viewXml.SelectSingleNode("//Query");

                if (viewQuery != null)
                 {
                     var where = viewQuery.SelectSingleNode("//Where");
                     if (where == null)
                     {
                         where = xml.CreateElement("Where");
                         viewQuery.AppendChild(where);
                     }

                    if (where.ChildNodes.Count == 1)
                     {
                         where.InnerXml = string.Format("<And>{0}{1}</And>", where.FirstChild.OuterXml, query);
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         if (queryCount > 1)
                         {
                             where.InnerXml = string.Format("<And>{0}</And>", query);
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             where.InnerXml = query;
                         }
                     }
                 }} 
webPart.XmlDefinition = xml.InnerXml;
```

But when the web part is connected to another webpart with a "Send Row of Data To" connection the
 webPart.XmlDefinition filtering hack doesn’t work any more.

Why?